# Smoked Pork Butt Question

Tags: meat, storage-method, pork, smoking

I’ve smoked two pork butts for 11 hours and they’re done- but I’ve not supposed to serve for 7 hours.  My plan is to keep itv warm in the oven at a low temperature.

Question is: should I wrap the meat in foil now and shred later, or shred now and keep everything warm?

Comment: @Joe I am removing that from the comment space, if you repost it as an answer, I would upvote.

Answer (score 3):

I would wrap the meat and keep it warm. Otherwise its likely to dry out in the oven at 7 hours, even at low heat.